# How to handler errors in abstract class PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo, error-handling

I have an abstract classes for update, select, delete and insert statements. in my database connection function, config.php I have

```
function dbconnect() 
{
            $dbh; // database handler
             $host = 'localhost';
             $user =  'root';
             $pass =  '';
             $dbname = '';
             $error;


                // Set DSN
                $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
                // Set options
                $options = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false

                );
                // Create a new PDO instanace
                try{
                    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
                }
                // Catch any errors
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    $error = $e->getMessage();
                }

               return $dbh;
           }
```

*notice  try catch an error*

in my abstract class.

```
   public function __construct() {
           $this->dbh = dbconnect();

       }

       public function query($query) {
           $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
       }

       public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
           if(is_null($type)) {
               switch (true) {
                   case is_int($value):
                       $type = PD0::PARAM_INT;
                       break;
                    case is_bool($value);
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value);
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default :
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
               }
           }
           $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
       }
 }
```

*My question*

In the construct I connect to the database which also means I am catching errors here and in the other function I have not error handling and I am not returning any errors in it. Is they any point in me having error handle in other functions I have and if yes how do you suggest I handle this? I am still need to PDO and OOP in general but I do try to do things the right way. Please advice

Comment: Well certainly you have to implement an error handling for all interactions with the database system. A query might throw an error, that is not caught by the error handling during connection setup. So what is the problem in that? Go along the style you use in the connection setup routine and all is fine. You don't have to do that in each method in that class. It is enough to add a try-catch block when _using_ that class in your code.

Comment: You should probably move the `dbConnect()` function to the constructor (or make it a private method of the class called from the constructor) and have `$error` as a class member. Then if `$dbh` throws an Exception when you attempt to connect you can retrieve the error information with a getter method.

Comment: For the whole my life I will never understand this strong desire of PHP users to create tons of code out of nowhere and for nothing. Just for sake of it.

Comment: @CD001 you believe having the dbconnect function inside the construct will be the best way in other for me not to have an error handler in every method?

Comment: @YourCommonSense its not for the sake of it. I am simply trying to do dbconnect in the right way. The code above works without any errors all i wanted to know was do i need an error handler in every function or just having it in the dbconnect function is okay? and if not i needs some professional advice.

Comment: I think what @YourCommonSense is getting at is that, unless you're likely to be switching between database connection engines (e.g. from `PDO` to `mysqli`) there's not really any need to abstract it at all - just use the PDO objects, you don't really need to make another class to map `myClass::prepare()` to `PDO::prepare()` - however, if you're trying to make a generic wrapper that would allow you to switch your entire engine from mysqli to PDO by changing a single config variable - then you're OK. e.g. `mysqli::real_escape_string()` and `PDO::quote()` return strings slightly differently.

Comment: The reason I'd put the `dbConnect()` functionality into the constructor is that I could then store `$dbh` AND `$error` variables in the class itself - whenever a query throws an error you can simply catch it and pass it to `$this->error` - if you're building a CRUD abstraction object (which I've done for part of a RBAS before) you'll only ever have 4 methods (create, read, update and delete) that actually execute queries and can trigger `PDOException`s - everything else calls one of those methods.

Comment: there is no point in having function bind() (save for the scarce chance of using placeholder for the limit parameter. All other cases are absolutely useless though). there is no point in function query(). there is no point in having abstract propotype.

Comment: At the same time Great Relational database dimishished to the rank of silly key-value storage, with just create, read, update and delete methods - without joins, views, grouping, conditional updating and many other things

Comment: @YourCommonSense : sounds like you spent too much time with MVC frameworks that seem to think the Model **is** the database :| The reason for create, read, update and delete methods is simply to 1: always return data in an expected format (an `UPDATE` statement might just return the number of rows affected whilst a `SELECT` will return a set of records, the `update` and `read` methods reflect this) and 2: to verify access permissions in an RBAS at the point of the query (rather than using a standard db->query method). It shouldn't affect your ability to use `JOIN`s, RDBMS or anything else.

Comment: @CD001 It seems you are, like all PHP users, confusing DB access class with model class. There should be no such methods in the former. As well as the latter should have no idea of connection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48487/discussion-between-cd001-and-your-common-sense)

Comment: @YourCommonSense ... which is what I was saying ... CRUD is in the db access layer ... the Models should model your "things" (products, whatever) **not** your database structure - but many PHP MVC frameworks seem to conflate the two. *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if you cannot connect to the database, there's no point in having any of the other code, right? Then simply *do not catch the exception*. The exception will bubble up and even prevent your class from being instantiated, which means you do not need to worry about error handling in any of the other code because it can never be executed. That's the point of throwing exceptions in constructors.

Exceptions are for signalling *exceptional circumstances*. If you cannot connect to the database, that's quite an exceptional circumstance. That renders your entire database layer non-functional. Throwing an exception from the database layer is the correct thing to do here, because the database layer is non-operational and cannot handle this problem itself. It needs to signal to the rest of the system that it cannot work and the rest of the system needs to decide what to do in this case. Catch the exception higher up in your app, if at all, and react to it by displaying an error page there.

For other exceptions which may happen during regular queries, the same rule applies. Decide whether the problem is recoverable and whether it makes sense to catch and handle it inside your database class, or whether an exception (which, again, is something which should never ever happen) means it's time to give up.

Comment: Em, and if the connection succeeds?

Comment: Then the case that the OP talks about is handled. Whether you want to handle exceptions thrown during regular queries inside the database layer or not depends on what kind of exceptional circumstances you encounter. If you're confident you can handle the error in a useful way inside the database layer, then catch it there and handle it. Otherwise, again, let it bubble up.

Comment: I can connect to the database deceze.

Comment: @user Did you get the gist of what I'm trying to tell you about exceptions and handling them?

Comment: @deceze i think so. from what you are saying it shows like its better for me to move my dbconnect int the construct so  i can be able to handler errors. correct me if am wrong

Comment: @user No. I'm saying that if you get errors, which surface as exceptions, simply do not `catch` those exceptions. Exceptions are meant to bubble up. That's their purpose. Only `catch` them if you have any constructive plan what to do with them. Just logging an error and then pretending as if nothing happened is not a constructive plan to handle exceptional errors.

Comment: @user3057514 you don't want to "handle" this error. because your idea of handling is essentially wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes please. Thats why I asked this question. I will really like your help

Comment: @user3057514 you have been told already. just DON'T handle this error at all.

Comment: @user Right. As I've been trying to tell you: what is your error handling strategy? An error means something happened that your code did not anticipate. If you're in a situation where something happened that you did not want and did not expect to happen, how can you continue to run the rest of your code?! You have no idea what just happened or didn't happen and what the current state of your application is. Continuing to execute code may only make matters worse. Therefore, don't catch the exception and let it *stop* your program.

Comment: @deceze thanks. I need to rethink this and educate myself more into oop and abstract classes

Comment: @deceze I am writing an error handle class and will post it when am done. I hope you will have some time to look at it once done thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only time you might need to handle an Exception in a constructor for a database wrapper is to ensure a particular **type** of Exception is thrown and bubbled up to the application - though I can only see this being useful if you're building a wrapper that can switch database connection objects.

If you're using a Factory pattern for instance that can create either a `mysqli` or a `PDO` object you might want the constructor to catch `mysqli::connect_error` (not an Excepton) AND `PDOException` and always throw a common `AppException` (which extends `Exception`).

So in the mysqli constructor you might simply have:

```
$dbConn = new mysqli($sHost, $sUsername, $sPassword, $sSchema, $iPort);

if($dbConn->connect_error) {
  throw new AppExecption(AppException::DB_CONNECT, $dbConn->connect_error);
}
```

Whilst in the PDO wrapper constructor you might have:

```
try {
  $dbConn = new PDO($sDSN, $sUsername, $sPassword);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
  throw new AppException(AppException::DB_CONNECT, $e->getMessage());
}
```

So you're not really handling the PDOException in the constructor - merely converting it into a common type of Exception which could be handled in a specific way when it's bubbled up to the application irrespective as to whether you're constructing a mysqli object or a PDO one.

Comment: I always wondered, why PHP users have such a strong belief, that only database-related errors deserve a nicely formatted HTML error page

Comment: What about ugly PHP warnings? They don't deserve a nicely formatted page?

Comment: So, just like other PHP users you are *really* believe that the person who building an application is the *only* its user - right? What about simple users who aren't building but rather want to buy or read some article? Do they really need that fluff? What about a potential hacker who wold be interested in that fluff?

Comment: To make myself clear - the main objection is that your idea of error handling is not clear and doesn't seem proper. While error handling is the only topic in question, with all the other code being quite irrelevant.

Comment: Deleted anything extraneous - I'm not sure why I felt the need to get into an internet p***ing match anyway.